# OpenBD isValid email fails .education domain

Tags: validation, email, cfml, openbd

I'm running OpenBD CFML isValid('email','something@whatever.education') and my result is 'NO'.

.education is a valid domain - why does this fail?

Comment: What version of OpenBD are you using?

Comment: the latest - 3.1

Comment: As luck would have it... (this is all based on Google searches). The [release date for OpenBD 3.1](http://openbd.org/notes/) appears to have been March 2014. The "education" TLD appears to have entered [general availability](https://web-solutions.eu/education-domain.htm) in April 2014. I think this version of OpenBD just doesn't support it.

Comment: The `isValid()` CFML function is known to be buggy anyway [example 1](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/265-coldfusion-email-validation-isvalid-and-cfmail-errors.htm), [example 2](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2593-isvalid-accepts-emails-with-leading-and-trailing-whitespace-in-coldfusion.htm). You would probably be better off using a RegEx of your own.

Comment: I have a RegEx that I'm prepared to use. Thanks for your input!

Comment: and that RegEx does not work, of course.  '^[-!#$%&\'*+\\./0-9=?A-Z^_`a-z{|}~]+@[-!#$%&\'*+\\/0-9=?A-Z^_`a-z{|}~]+\.[-!#$%&\'*+\\./0-9=?A-Z^_`a-z{|}~]+$'

Comment: There are plenty of examples out there. Maybe start with this one - [How to Find or Validate an Email Address](https://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out to be an issue with the regex used behind the scenes to match valid domains.

The regex in place didn't account for domains as long as "education".

I fixed it and it's been merged, should be in the nightly by now, grab the latest update and you should be able to use isValid("email", "AwesomeEmail@School.education") just fine. Viva la open source.